# Syntax error on token “OnClickListener”, = expected after this token

Tags: android, eclipse

I know another topic is exactly called this way, but it doesn't answer my problem.

Eclipse underlines `setOnClickListener` pointing at 
     `loc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
and says
Syntax error on token "setOnClickListener", = expected after this token.

I start practicing Android, and I think the solution is quite simple. Thank you in advance !

```
package com.example.vll;

import com.example.vll.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.Math;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private SensorManager mySensorManager;
private Sensor myGravitySensor;
private Sensor  myAccelerometerSensor;

TextView x_position_value;
TextView y_position_value;
TextView z_position_value;
TextView x_normal_vector_value;
TextView y_normal_vector_value;
TextView z_normal_vector_value;
TextView textLightSensor;

private float xPositionValue=0;
private float yPositionValue=0;
private float zPositionValue=0;

private float xAccelerometerValue=0;
private float yAccelerometerValue=0;
private float zAccelerometerValue=0;


private float xGravityValue=0;
private float yGravityValue=0;
private float zGravityValue=0;  

Button loc;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     loc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.localize);

     x_position_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_position_value);
     y_position_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y_position_value);
     z_position_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z_position_value);

     mySensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
     myGravitySensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
     myAccelerometerSensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

           if (myAccelerometerSensor == null){
            textLightSensor.setText("No Accelerometer Sensor!");
           }else{
            //mySensorManager.registerListener(GravitySensorEventListener, myGravitySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            mySensorManager.registerListener(AccelerometerSensorEventListener, myAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            }
   }

 SensorEventListener AccelerometerSensorEventListener
   = new SensorEventListener(){

    @Override
       public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

@Override
      public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

           xAccelerometerValue=event.values[0];
           yAccelerometerValue=event.values[1];
           zAccelerometerValue=event.values[2];

       }
     }};

 /*
   SensorEventListener GravitySensorEventListener
    = new SensorEventListener(){

       @Override
       public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

       @Override
       public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY){
               xGravityValue=event.values[0];
               yGravityValue=event.values[1];
               zGravityValue=event.values[2];
           }
        }
    };
     */

    //MY PROBLEM IS HERE    
    loc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            x_normal_vector_value.setText(" x = "+String.valueOf(xAccelerometerValue*Math.pow(Math.pow(Math.pow(xAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(yAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(zAccelerometerValue,2), 0.5), -1)));
            y_normal_vector_value.setText(" y = "+String.valueOf(yAccelerometerValue*Math.pow(Math.pow(Math.pow(xAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(yAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(zAccelerometerValue,2), 0.5), -1)));
            z_normal_vector_value.setText(" z = "+String.valueOf(zAccelerometerValue*Math.pow(Math.pow(Math.pow(xAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(yAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(zAccelerometerValue,2), 0.5), -1)));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I think problem is somewere else, can you upload full code of your activity ?

Comment: it should be inside method...i mean put code in onCreate method

Comment: try pressing `ctrl+shift+o` to import OnClickListener

Comment: @Fabien case of misplaced `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a case of misplaced `}`. Check them properly and using a IDE should not be that difficult

You need to change this

```
mySensorManager.registerListener(AccelerometerSensorEventListener,myAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
 } // else end here
} // onCreate brace end here.
```

to

```
mySensorManager.registerListener(AccelerometerSensorEventListener, myAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
 } // else end here
```

And have the brace `}` at the end

```
   });
  } // oncreate
 } // activity
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your `onClickListener` part is in the `onCreate` method scope.

Here is the correct code:

```
 package com.example.vll;

import com.example.vll.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.Math;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private SensorManager mySensorManager;
private Sensor myGravitySensor;
private Sensor  myAccelerometerSensor;

TextView x_position_value;
TextView y_position_value;
TextView z_position_value;
TextView x_normal_vector_value;
TextView y_normal_vector_value;
TextView z_normal_vector_value;
TextView textLightSensor;

private float xPositionValue=0;
private float yPositionValue=0;
private float zPositionValue=0;

private float xAccelerometerValue=0;
private float yAccelerometerValue=0;
private float zAccelerometerValue=0;


private float xGravityValue=0;
private float yGravityValue=0;
private float zGravityValue=0;


Button loc;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     loc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.localize);

     x_position_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_position_value);
     y_position_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y_position_value);
     z_position_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z_position_value);

     mySensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
     myGravitySensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
     myAccelerometerSensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

           if (myAccelerometerSensor == null){
            textLightSensor.setText("No Accelerometer Sensor!");
           }else{
            //mySensorManager.registerListener(GravitySensorEventListener, myGravitySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            mySensorManager.registerListener(AccelerometerSensorEventListener, myAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            }

 //MY PROBLEM IS HERE 
    loc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            x_normal_vector_value.setText(" x = "+String.valueOf(xAccelerometerValue*Math.pow(Math.pow(Math.pow(xAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(yAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(zAccelerometerValue,2), 0.5), -1)));
            y_normal_vector_value.setText(" y = "+String.valueOf(yAccelerometerValue*Math.pow(Math.pow(Math.pow(xAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(yAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(zAccelerometerValue,2), 0.5), -1)));
            z_normal_vector_value.setText(" z = "+String.valueOf(zAccelerometerValue*Math.pow(Math.pow(Math.pow(xAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(yAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(zAccelerometerValue,2), 0.5), -1)));
        }
    });


   }

 SensorEventListener AccelerometerSensorEventListener
   = new SensorEventListener(){

    @Override
       public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

@Override
      public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

           xAccelerometerValue=event.values[0];
           yAccelerometerValue=event.values[1];
           zAccelerometerValue=event.values[2];

       }
     }};

 /*
   SensorEventListener GravitySensorEventListener
    = new SensorEventListener(){

       @Override
       public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

       @Override
       public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY){
               xGravityValue=event.values[0];
               yGravityValue=event.values[1];
               zGravityValue=event.values[2];
           }
        }
    };
     */


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was only an extra `}` at line number 69 , I just removed it. You can paste following code in your project, and it will work properly,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SensorManager mySensorManager;
    private Sensor myGravitySensor;
    private Sensor  myAccelerometerSensor;

    TextView x_position_value;
    TextView y_position_value;
    TextView z_position_value;
    TextView x_normal_vector_value;
    TextView y_normal_vector_value;
    TextView z_normal_vector_value;
    TextView textLightSensor;

    private float xPositionValue=0;
    private float yPositionValue=0;
    private float zPositionValue=0;

    private float xAccelerometerValue=0;
    private float yAccelerometerValue=0;
    private float zAccelerometerValue=0;


    private float xGravityValue=0;
    private float yGravityValue=0;
    private float zGravityValue=0;


    Button loc;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.localize);

        x_position_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_position_value);
        y_position_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y_position_value);
        z_position_value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z_position_value);

        mySensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        myGravitySensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
        myAccelerometerSensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        if (myAccelerometerSensor == null){
            textLightSensor.setText("No Accelerometer Sensor!");
        }else{
            //mySensorManager.registerListener(GravitySensorEventListener, myGravitySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            mySensorManager.registerListener(AccelerometerSensorEventListener, myAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        }


        SensorEventListener AccelerometerSensorEventListener
        = new SensorEventListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

                    xAccelerometerValue=event.values[0];
                    yAccelerometerValue=event.values[1];
                    zAccelerometerValue=event.values[2];

                }
            }};

            /*
   SensorEventListener GravitySensorEventListener
    = new SensorEventListener(){

       @Override
       public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

       @Override
       public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY){
               xGravityValue=event.values[0];
               yGravityValue=event.values[1];
               zGravityValue=event.values[2];
           }
        }
    };
             */

            //MY PROBLEM IS HERE    
            loc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    x_normal_vector_value.setText(" x = "+String.valueOf(xAccelerometerValue*Math.pow(Math.pow(Math.pow(xAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(yAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(zAccelerometerValue,2), 0.5), -1)));
                    y_normal_vector_value.setText(" y = "+String.valueOf(yAccelerometerValue*Math.pow(Math.pow(Math.pow(xAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(yAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(zAccelerometerValue,2), 0.5), -1)));
                    z_normal_vector_value.setText(" z = "+String.valueOf(zAccelerometerValue*Math.pow(Math.pow(Math.pow(xAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(yAccelerometerValue,2)+Math.pow(zAccelerometerValue,2), 0.5), -1)));
                }
            });
    }
}
```